# Url changes after I ship an order - Magento

Tags: php, magento

Running Mangento 1.7.0.2 in multistore/multidomain environment. When I ship an order (Click Submit Shipment in admin), the url changes from the admin to my domain.

for example:

URL before:

http://adminurl.com/index.php/admin....

After submitting shipment url redirects to:

http://domain1.com/index.php/admin....

Any idea as to why this happens? It only started happening recently.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- disable any shipping 3rd party extensions, also extensions which improves checkout process
- disable your custom theme
- use default .htaccess file